# What regex detects bullets in Google docs?

Tags: regex, google-docs

I'm using Google docs find and replace feature to remove repeating content. When I'm done I end up with a empty bullets and I don't know how to remove them using regex.

Comment: I would say to test something like find `(\n)(.)` and replace `$1$2`, but on Google docs I don't manage to use regex with capturing groups at all.

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you looking for? What kind of "repeated content" would you expect to be removed from [this google document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uazAQ7ruof1Fp2hUAN6PrFSBXpU7hVQV18HqSrIcTkw/edit?usp=sharing)?

Comment: @Addison I want to remove bullets with nothing after them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a way to touch the bullet points with find and replace, other than perhaps exporting the document as plain text and editing that.

The reason lies in the fact that they aren't physical characters - but instead modifiers associated with a line, very similar to indents (they really are just indents with a special symbol).

Because of this, they can't be edited - find and replace will skim right over them like they aren't there. The following example searches for newlines which are directly followed by another newline. You can see that it doesn't discriminate between bullet points and other lines.

> [image: Find and replace on google docs]